# NPoco: Update some (but not all) columns using Expression notation

Tags: c#, lambda, orm, npoco

Using NPoco, I'm trying to figure out how to update more than one column of an object (but not all of them).  This works...

```
db.Update(item, new[] { "status", "tracking_number", "updated_at" });
```

...but I'm trying to use the notation below so I can use my object's property names rather than the database column names.

```
int Update<T>(T poco, Expression<Func<T, object>> fields);
```

How do I list more than one column using the above syntax?  This will update a single column but I assume I can list more than one but I can't figure out the notation.

```
db.Update(item, i => i.Status);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking through the code, it seems you use an anonymous object:

```
x => x.SomeProperty1 or x => new{ x.SomeProperty1, x.SomeProperty2}
```

so in your example:

```
db.Update(item, i => new { i.Status, i.TrackingNumber, i.UpdatedAt });
```

Comment: That did it.  Thanks